# If "getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu)" is not from Activity Class, so why default project in android studio works well?

Tags: java, android

I know java and but this is question for me that if "getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu)" is not from Activity Class, so why default project in android studio works well? In the following code, Activity class is a parent class. But there are not getMenuInflater() And inflate(....., ....) in Activity class. It is not reasonable.

```
package com.exaample.pro;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean this [getMenuInflater()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getMenuInflater()) ?

Comment: getMenuInflater() is a method of Activity class

Answer (score 1):

`getMenuInflater()` is a method on `Activity`, as you can see in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getMenuInflater()).

[`inflate()` is a method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.Menu)) on `MenuInflater`, the type of object returned by `getMenuInflater()`.

Comment: thank you for all. But for using inflate() we do not import  MenuInflater Class in header.??

Comment: @developer: You only need an `import` statement in Java if you are declaring a local variable, data member, or something like that as an instance of a particular class. So, if we wanted to have `MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();`, then we would need to have an `import` statement for `MenuInflater`.